# (Entity framework) Group by - low performance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I have very peculiar problem with performance of Entity Framework. I use version 7 of the framework with SQLite provider (both from nuget). Database have around 10 millions of records but in the future there will be around 100 millions. The construction of db is very simple:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int SampleID { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public short Channel { get; set; } /* values from 0 to 8191, in the presented test 0-15 */
    public byte Events { get; set; } /* 1-255 */
}

public class Channel
{
    public int ChannelID { get; set; }
    public short Ch { get; set; }
    public int Es { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // This property defines the table
    public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Channel> Spectrum { get; set; }

    // This method connects the context with the database
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "E://database.db" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
}
```

I try to group events by channel and sum them up into something like spectrum. When I use linq2sql I have very low performance. For 10m of records the query takes about 15 minutes and get around 1 GB of RAM and then throws an OutOfMemoryException - I think that Entity Framework is loading all records as objects into memory - but why? On the other hand, simple SQL needs about 3 seconds and takes no significant amount of RAM.

```
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var res1 = from sample in db.Samples
                       group sample by sample.Channel into g
                       select new { Channel=g.Key, Events = g.Sum(s => s.Events) };
            res1.ToArray();

            var res2 = db.Natas.FromSql("SELECT Channel as ChannelID, Channel as Ch, SUM(Events) as Es FROM Sample GROUP BY Channel");
            var data = res2.ToArray();
        }
```

Any suggestions? Thank for help ;)

Comment: Why do you need 'orderby'?

Comment: I use order by to get results in proper order (maybe I should use it after grouping) - in this case it have no importance - after removing this part of linq, performance is still the same. 

I removed the part of OrderBy in the question's code to make it more clearer.

Comment: But the order by is not in the "much faster pure sql". You compare apples to oranges unless the SQL is functionally identical.

Comment: Have you checked the query which is generated by EF and sent to the database?

Comment: The SQLite provider for EF in the nawest version have a problem with showing SQL ;/ - that's why I decided to ask this question here.

Comment: I removed the oerder by in linq - as I said before, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion? IGNORE ENTITY FRAMEWORK.

As in: this is so totally not an EF issue it is not even funny.

Look at the SQL that EF sends out, then optimize from that level. Oh, you have little influence on the SQL; but for a trivial statement like this the SQL will be optimal.

What will not be optimal - and there is a hint you never looked at the SQL - is the database. Are the indices there? Code first is amazing in that it is ignorant to the intricacies of the database and you need to look at it FIRST from a "is my database optimal". Indices. And - sadly - hardware. If you hit 100 million rows, you need to have the power in the database to handle this.

> I think that Entity Framework is loading all records as objects into memory - 
>   but why?

Rule 1 in performance dbugging: DO NOT THINK - CHECK. Look at the SQL generated (log, the res1 variable can show you) and see what gets submitted to the database.

It is possible that you just have that much data. You say nothing about how many channels exist - this may well require a bigger machine.

Check it.

Also: it is not really smart to pull the results into an array unless you need that. Arrays are memory problematic in this scenario (reallocations to get the size) and a LIST may be better (uses more memory but requires no reallocation). In general, though, you want to AVOID materializing the result sets - i.e. work from the enumerable. Not always, but your test may simple show problems on that side. The resulting array may be hugh. And require one piece of memory.

And seriously, question your selection of database technology. SqlLite is nice - it is small, it is lightweight. It is in memory. It is NOT suitable for hugh amounts of data, it is not a full scale database server. You may be much better off using Sql Express (if anything: SQL express will use memory for caching that is NOT in your process but separate). I personally would not use SqlLite for something that may use hundreds of millions of records.

Also: Note your SQL is different. The EF Part has an OrderBy (which is not needed), the SQL not. Ordering may well be expensive. Which puts us back to "get the SQL generated by entity framework".

Comment: I tried to check generated SQL. Unfortunately the actual version of EF have some problems with showing the SQL while using SQLite provider. So I have no ability to check it. I looked at the chart of RAM usage in Visual Studio and see that the usage was still raising.

I have simple choice between database in single file (SQLite) and binary file. My experience said that db will be better optimized by the engine  rather than my solution. The program will be used in physics experiment and the requirement is that the solution should be in single file.

Comment: The result of the query will have up to 8192 rows (in the tested scenario there is only 16). The orderby statement have no impact (checked). All data will be used to generate chart so there is no space for lazy loading.

Comment: Well, that leaves you with a problem. For stuff like that - consider NOT using EF. A good alternative is Linq2DB, which is a "half ORM". It does a lot - and better - sql to LINQ mapping, but no higher functions. BUt it is great for reporting, being super fast. It is possible you have a SqlLite issue. I suggest, as next step, then to use a - memory profiler to see where the memory is lost. And try to make ToList THEN ToArray, which may be more efficient (no resizing) under memory constraint.

Comment: Thank you. To be honest, I choosed EF beacues I saw the opportunity to learn this stuff. But of course I will try mentioned Linq2DB.

Answer (score -3):

The problem was connected with SQLite provider. After change to SQL Server Compact everything works fine ;)

Comment: This answer needs a more detailed description of the changes that were made.